# PHP - How to do an action between time position?

Tags: php

I am trying to code this but i can't.
I spend two hours to do this but i can't figure.

```
$offset=8*60*60; 
$timeFormat="H:i";
$timeNow=gmdate($timeFormat, time()+$offset);
if ($timeNowis 09:00 up to 21:00){
echo "I'm online";
}else{
echo "I'm offline";
}
```

can somebody help me?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I would do:

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');

$open = mktime(9,0,0,date("n"),date("j"),date("Y"));
$closed = mktime(21,0,0,date("n"),date("j"),date("Y"));

if(time() >= $open && time() <= $closed){
    echo 'online';
}else{
    echo 'offline';
}
```

or if you wanted to use `strtotime()`:

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');

if(time() >= strtotime('9:00') && time() <= strtotime('21:00')){
    echo 'online';
}else{
    echo 'offline';
}
```

Comment: This fits my requirements.. thanks a lot dude..

Answer (score 1):

you could do

```
$hour = intval(date('G'));
if($hour >= 9 && $hour < 21)
    echo "I'm online";
else
    echo "I'm offline";
```